# Access Controller context in custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm implementing a custom validator by using a ValidationAttribute:

```
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But to run the validation I need access to a variable which is part of the application's base controller (it's related to the user currently logged in). How can I get my hands on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can populate a model property with the variable you can do this:

Model:

```
[CustomAttribute("MyVariableAsModelProperty", "Failed Validation!")
public string ValidateThis{get; set;}
public string MyVariableAsModelProperty{get; set;}
```

Your custom validator:

```
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    string otherPropertyName;
    public CustomAttribute(string otherPropertyName, string errorMessage)
                : base(errorMessage)
           {
                this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
            }
            protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
                var referenceProperty = (string)otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                //...
            }
```

Now you have the 2 values to compare: `value` is the model property to be validated, and `referenceProperty` is the variable.